# Removing wiaaut.dll from system

Tags: c#, wia

I am using `C#` to build a small project which scans a image.I am using `WIA` for this purpose.I have registered the `wiaaut.dll`, my question to you guys is that how do I unregister or remove the `wiaaut.dll`, what command should I use.
Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can just put that dll into you program folder, near exe. So you don`t need to register it and unregister as well

Comment: @JieruOHeP, but I have already registered the .dll file using the command regsvr32 wiaaut.dll

Comment: @JieruOHeP, could you give me a example , I am not able to make it out

Comment: @JieruOHeP , oops did not see the link , sorry , will try that